# Format number to time d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
date,lenght,sort
201506131449,2,1
201506131449,7,0
201506131450,35,1
201506131450,7,1
```

But then a lot more entries.

De date is currently formated like
201506131450 which is 2015 - 06 - 13 14:50 where 14:50 is military time so (2:50pm)

I need to keep the format like this for sorting purposes in python.

Anyway. Right now The labels output the huge number. While I only want the military time part.

So 201506131450 should be labeld 14:50

Current code:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

This produce the labels on the x axis like: 201,506,131,600

How can I change that to 16:00

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your axis, set the `tickFormat`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d){
    return d.toString().slice(8,10) + ":" + d.toString().slice(10);
});
```

Demo:

```js
var dates = [201506131449, 201506131449, 201506131450,201506131450];

dates.forEach(function(d){
    console.log(d.toString().slice(8,10) + ":" + d.toString().slice(10))
});
```

PS: keep in mind that, for the scale, this is not a time, this is just a linear scale of numbers.